# Insert value to new column in oauth_access_tokens in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I use grant personal password in laravel passport and in `oauth_access_tokens` I added new column "device" to specific `access_token` for each device.
And when I make a request to `http://example.com/oauth/token`, it creates token in `oauth_access_token` and `oauth_refresh_token` table but column `" device"` is `null`.

I can update `"device"` column but how can I set value for "device" column in the same request to `http://example.com/oauth/token`

Comment: Were you able to solve this?